# Is HEREDOC still used?

Tags: php, xhtml

I am reading an old "for Dummies" book and came across a section about heredocs output.
Is this still (or was it ever) common coding practice?

```
print <<<HERE
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            This is an example!
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
HERE;
```

Comment: Yes it is still used. It's handy when you're writing a string with lots of single and double quotes. There's nothing wrong with using it. Although if you're feeing it to a print statement, you might just be better off closing and re-opening the PHP tags.

Comment: I just noticed that the code block is not recognizing it. Should I take that as my answer?

Comment: Are you saying heredocs should be used with echo v. print?

Comment: `echo` is slightly faster, but you shouldn't really care. Use whatever the rest of your code base uses.

Comment: Naysayers down voting and closing... Whatever, I learned a few things, despite how big or small it was. So thanks for taking the time to respond and not just shrugging me off. Though, a few more down votes and Ill delete the question and earn myself a badge too!

Comment: +1 for the good question. Too bad it was closed. The answer is simple - for the very example you posted, just change `print <<<HERE` to `?>` and `HERE;` to `<?PHP` and you will get WAY more reliable way of doing such things.

Comment: Yeah, usually I do just break in and out of PHP as needed, that is why I was wondering if this is common practice. Though I guess it could still be useful to apply variables to long HTML without breaking back into PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's used, although I tend to use NOWDOC more often. It really shines when you want to keep some string formatted with indents, exactly like your example. Not necessarily just HTML, but any formatted syntax without having to worry about concatenation ugliness.

Comment: I thought you were trolling me just a little bit for a minute there, but it basically comes down to what is escaped and expanded, correct?

Comment: Correct. HEREDOC treats the contents as a double quoted string, and NOWDOC treats the contents as a single quoted string. Same rules.

Comment: -1. If you change print `<<<HERE` to `?>` and `HERE;` to `<?PHP` in their example you will get WAY more reliable code.

Comment: I don't believe this answer was unhelpful. It explains exactly what heredoc and nowdoc do, regardless if the OP's example isn't the ideal scenario. Your downvote was unwarranted.